# Why make/buy a washing cup with only one handle?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

The purpose of a washing cup is to purify the hands. There are two handles on most washing cups. This allows us to avoid transmitting impurity from the unwashed hand to the washed hand by way of the wet, washed/pure hand touching the unwashed hand.  With two handles, the pure hand can take the cup from the unwashed hand by using the handle that the unwashed hand is not holding, and then the washed hand can pour water on the unwashed/impure hand so both hands are pure.  It would seem that to achieve the same effect with one handle, one would have to put the cup down and then pick it up again with the other hand.  That seems cumbersome, at best.

Yet, I have seen one handled washing cups in some rather frum places.

Why would someone make or buy a one handled washing cup?  Is there good halachic or practical reason for a one handle washing cup?

Comment: Sourcing all the assumptions in this post would greatly improve it.

Comment: @mevaqesh Are there any assumptions that call out to you for support? Or is your comment just a general one on MY style?

Comment: 1) The purpose of a washing cup is to purify the hands 2) This allows us to avoid transmitting impurity from the unwashed hand to the washed hand by way of the wet, washed/pure hand touching the unwashed hand

Comment: I have seen many people wash their hands with a yahrtzeit glass. Why do you think any handle is needed?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/662893/jewish/Why-the-two-handled-washing-cup.htm

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60668/rules-about-handles-on-the-vessel-for-netilas-yadayim

Comment: If you use a revi'is (=volume of a kiddush cup) in one go to wash your hands there is no impure water. See O Ch 162 (1) towards the end and in many other places in these halochos. So then you do not need two handles.

Comment: The Chabad custom is as follows: the kvort is picked up in the right hand, passed to the left hand, and poured over the right hand three times. Next, the kvort is passed to the right hand, with a towel between the handle and the washer's hand and poured over the left hand three times. ... Thus, it seems in this case the second handle is not necessary in the Chabad world because we are using a towel between our hand and the handle anyway.

Comment: @mevaqesh  Is the Chabad URL posted by GG enough support for you or are you looking for citations to the sources?

Comment: Looks good to me.