# Do kashrut rules apply to a Washing laver?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, netilat-yadayim-washing

Are there any halachot that apply the rules of kashrut to the cup I use to wash my hands before I eat?

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60668/rules-about-handles-on-the-vessel-for-netilas-yadayim) answer says that one can use "any cup". [This](http://dinonline.org/2011/11/07/drunk-and-labored-water-for-netilas-yadayim/) site says that a cup can be drunk from and the water can still be used so I thought that this meant that the cup for washing doesn't have to be a dedicated washing cup and can be used for foodstuffs otherwise.

If I am about to eat a cheese sandwich, may I wash with a handled cup that was recently holding beef gravy but has been rinsed out? What if the cup held a non-kosher beef gravy? What if the cup held nothing, but was washed in hot water with dishes that were used for milchigs/fleishigs/treif food -- is there a "status" to the cup that could contraindicate its use at particular times?

Comment: Are you washing with water that is yad soledet bo?

Comment: @DoubleAA what's the difference? _Chay eno bolea_.

Comment: @msh210 If the water is cold then it hasn't absorbed any flavor. Perhaps the OP was concerned that having Treif water on your hands wouldn't effect Taharah (a la https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83621/759) or would possibly fall onto the food.